# How to set width and height of element's svg background imported by a gulp-svg-sprite npm package?

Tags: html, css, svg, gulp

For my project (website), I am using an NPM package named gulp-svg-sprite, which puts all my SVG images into one file sprites.svg and generates sprites.css.

In sprites.css, there are CSS classes which have their `background-image` property set to the svg image inside sprite.svg.

*sprites.css:*

```
.icon:before {
    content: ' ';
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(/img/sprite.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 71.7em 114.4em;
}
.icon.icon-logo:before {
    background-position: 0em -98.5em;
    width: 42.4em;
    height: 8.6em;
}
```

Displaying desired SVG image in *index.html*:

```
<span class="icon icon-logo"></span>
```

**Problem**: the SVG background image is too big

**Attempt to solve the problem** - trying to resize it, but it's not working:

*index.html:*

```
<style>
  .icon-logo:before {
     width: 130px;
     height: auto;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your sprites use `em` units for sizing and positioning, you need to change `font-size` instead of `width` and `height`, e.g. :

```
.icon-logo:before {
     font-size:.8em;
  }
```